# jQuery Validation plugin custom method using regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, jquery-validate

I need to make a new method for jQuery Validator and don't know where to start.

I would like it check that the email entered includes: '@specificdomain.com'.

But that it is also the very last part of the input. For example @specificdomain.comChris would not do.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.validator.addMethod("mustinclude", function(value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || value == ?
        }, "must include @specificdomain.com at the end of the text input");

    $(document).ready(function(){ .....
```

So far I've only come across value == value.match(), hence this is where I've got stuck.

Cheers Chris

```
        jQuery.validator.addMethod('matchDomain', function(value, element) {
        var s=value;
        var split = s.split('@');
        var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-])+$/;
        var s2="@allcoles.com";
        var optionalValue = this.optional(element);

        if (optionalValue) {
            return optionalValue;
            }
        if(regex.test(split[0]) && s2.equals(split[1]))
            {
            return true;
            }
        else
            {
            return false;
            }
        }, 'Please specify a @allcoles.com email');
```

Comment: There are literally many dozens of working `.addMethod()` examples inside [the `additional-methods.js` file.  Looking at those rules](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/additional-methods.js) would be a great place to learn how it's done.

Comment: Thank you, I couldn't find the method or anything close to it but it did help me find what I needed to do with the element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following worked for me:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod('matchDomain', function(value, element) {
        var s=value;
        var split = s.split('@');
        var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-])+$/;
        **var s2="allcoles.com";**                  //The split array is the domain excluding the @
        **var optionalValue = this.optional(element);** //This is how other methods in alternativeMethods.js Validator handle this.

        **//Debugging - This is useful to see visually what is happening
        //alert(split[0]);  // Shows the inputted username i.e chris or smokey
        //alert(split[1]);  // Shows the inputted domain
        //alert(regex.test(split[0]));  //Shows unfilled inputs problem or bad characters, true if good, false if bad
        //alert(s2 == split[1]);**  // Shows if the inputted domain matches variable s2, if it does we get a true

        if (optionalValue) {
            return optionalValue;
            }
        **if(regex.test(split[0]) && (s2 == split[1]))**  // has to be == not equals
            {
            return true;
            }
        else
            {
            return false;
            }
        }, 'Please specify a @allcoles.com email');
```

Comment: Please edit to point out where this code differs from your OP.  When writing questions and answers, keep in mind that SO is also a learning tool for future readers.

Comment: I added my answer to help others, I know its a learning tool.  I have however edited my post with bold to point out the 3 changes.  Apologies for not doing this.

Comment: You have the right idea and please don't think I'm being picky, but a brief verbal description (or inline comments) would be far better than adding asterisks inside code.  I'm trying to make the point that explaining something is better than expecting somebody to do a side-by-side comparison.

Answer (score 1):

```
var s="abc@specificdomain.com";  OR  var s=value;
var split = s.split('@');
var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-])/;
var s2="@specificdomain.com";

if(regex.test(split[0]) &&  s2 == split[1])

       return true;
else
         return false;
```

Comment: Hi thank you for the help; I added it in a addMethod.  I don't think I understand the return types correctly as its not working correctly.  Cheers Chris

Comment: Its a JQuery Validator addMethod http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/, ive confused myself as im not sure if im returning a Boolean false or an element.  I amended my original post to include your code

Comment: @Smokey, You should **always** return a boolean `true` or `false` from the function in the `.addMethod()` method.

Comment: s2.equals(split[1])).  I guess this is an array, should my var s2 be specificdomain.com and not @specificdomain.com?

Comment: Almost there equals not being == was the problem, and the s2 split did not need an @.  But I would not have got this working without your help.